# Go functions writing to the same map

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am trying to familiarize with go routines. I have written the following simple program to store the squares of numbers from 1-10 in a map.

```
func main() {
    squares := make(map[int]int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        go func(n int, s map[int]int) {
            s[n] = n * n
        }(i, squares)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Squares::: ", squares)
}
```

At the end, it prints an empty map. But in go, maps are passed by references. Why is it printing an empty map?

Comment: A sync.WaitGroup does no magic: You **must** call wg.Add before starting a goroutine and wg.Done inside the goroutine once done.

Comment: But if you properly use a sync.WaitGroup your code would still be wrong: You **must** **not** write to the same map concurrently. This simply is **not** **allowed**. You should guard the individual writes with a sync.Mutex instead if just making sure all goroutines are done with a syc.WaitGroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to synchronize access to the map and your usage of `sync.WaitGroup` is incorrect.

Try this instead:

```
func main() {
    squares := make(map[int]int)
    var lock sync.Mutex
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1) // Increment the wait group count
        go func(n int, s map[int]int) {
            lock.Lock() // Lock the map
            s[n] = n * n
            lock.Unlock()
            wg.Done() // Decrement the wait group count
        }(i, squares)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Squares::: ", squares)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) is what you are actually looking for, modified the code to suit your usecase here,

https://play.golang.org/p/DPLHiMsH5R8

P.S. Had to add some sleep so that the program does not finish before all the go routines are called.